# How to update encryption key in php?

Tags: php

I'm using `openssl_encrypt()` function with `AES cipher` in php to encrypt and decrypt some of my data and store it in database. I want to update my encryption/decryption key every 15 days or so manually. How can I achieve this? and is it possible to decrypt previously encrypted data, with the old encryption key, with new key?

Comment: You'd need to re-encrypt every data every 15 days, if you dispose all the previous keys.

Comment: "is it possible to decrypt previously encrypted data, with the old encryption key, with new key?"...no. if it was, then there would be no point in having encryption because any key could decrypt any data. Why are you wanting to change the key so frequently? If you're worried about security, the important thing is to make sure the key is stored securely